# Getting error when I use Media Query in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
     final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ( !kisweb || screenSize <= 600) ? MyHomePageMobile() : MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );

  }
```

[I am getting this error and I have no idea how to solve it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhvQe.png)

Comment: LayoutBuilder is a lot easier to use.  I suggest looking at it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare the MediaQuery above the Material app and it needs context. So the proper declaration should be like this.

```
class Main extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Test(),
    );
  }
}



   
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(
      child: Scaffold(
    body: ( !kisweb || screenSize <= 600) ? MyHomePageMobile() : MyHomePage(),
  ),
    );
  }
}
```